# Admin can't add images for product

Tags: product, image

I have different admins adding products for different categories. One of them has gotten back to me to say they cannot see the image upload control. I would normally advise it is an issue with Flash on the computer, but he is adamant that his Flash is up to date and present.

I will be performing a few more investigations for them, but would there be any other reason why they might not be able to see the control?

Comment: Since it's just one user reporting it ask him what browser he's using and perhaps also try another browser. It's probably either Flash or Javascript that's throwing an error

Comment: Yeah have asked for that information, am waiting for a response, just wondering if there may be another issue.

Comment: I've encountered a lot of issues. Mainly on Internet Explorer (as usual) or Firefox running some plugin that messes up stuff. Since it's only one user  that has this problem it'll probably be some weird fluke bug

Comment: We have an issue with one customer which has the same problem. We think it is a filtering mechanism in the LAN, because it doesn't work in any browser, but flash does.

Comment: I have also seen this happen before. In our case it was a js issue. If you can, ask him to right-click inspect element on the page and look at the js console. It will likely tell you where it is breaking.

Comment: We've had two compatibility issues which were difficult to trace. One was Internet Explorer treating the website as an intranet-site, because their network determined the domain was internal due to the way it was set-up for e-mails. The other was caused by a divx plugin replacing a function.